# How to add a table to shopware database without re-installing plugin?

Tags: orm, doctrine, shopware

I am afraid that I will lose data from the existing plugin if I reinstall it.

So, I would like to know is there any update that I can do in order to add a table and to avoid reinstallation and losing data.

Comment: Why you want to reinstall plugin? You can update it. Or you can create temp table while uninstall process and then transfer data from temp table to plugin table and delete temp one.

Answer (score 2):

this is easily possible by using the plugin lifecycle. Depending on the plugin system version you are using, the base class to extend in your plugin class differs a little bit: It may be either the [current one](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/engine/Shopware/Components/Plugin.php) or the [legacy one](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/engine/Shopware/Components/Plugin/Bootstrap.php).

Both contain a method called `update` that the place you are looking for.

If you want to learn more:

- You might book the free udemy [course concerned with plugin development](https://developers.shopware.com/blog/2018/01/31/free-online-course-shopware-developer-basic-training/)
- Take a look at the [plugin docs](https://developers.shopware.com/plugin-guide/)